# Key Error: None of the [Index[Columns] are in the Columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, error-handling, keyerror

```
import pandas as pd
customer_master_loc = r"D:\LOC_RUN\LOC_2021\2021_SP_INPUT_FILES\loc_cust_master_new_rules_09072021.txt"
customer_master_df = pd.read_csv(customer_master_loc,sep = '|',error_bad_lines=False,dtype = str)
customer_master_df = customer_master_df[['CUSTOMER_NUM','CUSTOMER_NAME','CUSTOMER_NAME2','CUSTOMER_ADDR_LN1', \
                                         'CUSTOMER_ADDR_LN2','CUSTOMER_ADDR_LN3','CUSTOMER_ADDR_LN4', \
                                         'CUSTOMER_CITY','STATE_CD','CUSTOMER_ZIP_BASE','COUNTY','SALESBLOCK_CD', \
                                         'ORGANIZATION_CD','LOSER_FLAG','SHARED_CUSTOMER_NUM','SHARED_CUSTOMER_FLAG','SHARED_CUSTOMER_ORGANIZATION_CD','WINNER_CUSTOMER_NUM','WINNER_CUSTOMER_FLAG','WINNER_CUSTOMER_ORGANIZATION_CD']]
```

Comment: it seems that the column names are not what you think 
try to print the head of the df before the filter the columns 
customer_master_df.head()

Comment: Check if the columns you need are returned by 'customer_master_df.columns', otherwise you need to check better your txt source file.

Comment: the column headers in source file were in lower case & in the code the columns were mentioned in upper case. i fixed this mismatch in source file and the error has been removed.
Thanks everyone!